# Understanding the lemma used in the proof of the inverse function theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am trying to understand the proof of this lemma which is used to prove the full inverse function theorem:
[image]

[image]

[image]

I am trying to understand part b) in particular the line that says $df_s$ ( the jacobian matrix ) is non-singular. Because this was neither previously proven nor assumed, so I don't know why $df_s$ would be non-singular.

Answer (score 1):

If $T$ is a linear transformation such that $\|T-I||<1$ then $T$ is non-singular. [Here we actually have $\|T-I||<\frac 1  2$]. Proof: $Tx=0$ and $x \neq 0$  implies $\|x\|=\|Tx-x\|\leq \|T-I\|\|x|| <\|x\|$, contradiction.  Hence, the kernel of $T$ is $\{0\}$ and so $T$ is non-singular.

Comment: Thank you. I am also a bit stuck trying to figure out why $d\phi(s)=0$ implies $df_s(f(s)-t)=0$. I wrote out the jacobian matrix, but the terms just don't line up with  $d\phi(s)$. It looks like the indices just don't match up at all.

Comment: @davidh Write $\phi(s)$ as $\langle (f(s)-t), (f(s)-t) \rangle$ and use Chain Rule.